# p:dataScroller in two tabs lazy loading when initial chunk of results is small

Tags: primefaces

In a PF12 application, I have a search engine with two types of documents, let's call them students and teachers. The user chooses the type of documents for which to navigate the results through a tab.
I'm facing two issues:

1. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, both tabs get their content expanded (although only the current tab is visually updated). This is bothering in the following scenario:
   1.a. The user scrolls to see 10 students.
   1.b. The user goes to the next tab and scrolls to see 50 teachers.
   1.c. The user goes back to the first tab and sees there the bottom of 50 students (instead of the original 10 students).
   This can be partially solved through `mode="inline"`. But with that I need to set `scrollHeight` as well. I'd rather use the entire available space instead of indicating a fixed height in pixels.
2. When the page is long enough to fit all initial 10 students/teachers, it is not possible to continue loading because the scrollbar isn't visible. Is there a way to dynamically keep loading until the page is full and the scrollbar becomes available for further scrolling?

```
<h:form>
  <p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="true">
    <p:tab title="Students">
      <ul>
        <p:dataScroller value="#{search.students}" var="student" chunkSize="10" lazy="true">
          <li>#{student.id}</li>
        </p:dataScroller>
      </ul>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Teachers">
      <ul>
        <p:dataScroller value="#{search.teachers}" var="teacher" chunkSize="10" lazy="true">
          <li>#{teacher.id}</li>
        </p:dataScroller>
      </ul>
    </p:tab>
  </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Comment: @JasperdeVries, can you please elaborate? It's not clear to me how to apply your suggestion.

Comment: Can you please add a runnable reproducer? https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test